# Trim blank space from SVG - Fabric JS

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

I'm trying to add an SVG letter to a fabricjs canvas. When i import it the width stays at 1000 when the letter isn't actually that width. It's important the width is the true width of the character otherwise the calculations for the space between letters is way off. Here's the svg data for the letter:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1000 1000;" xml:space="preserve">
<path d="M586,504.5h0.2c-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.8-0.1-1.2c0-0.4,0.1-0.8,0.1-1.2H586c-0.8-12.2,3.9-24.2,16-37.3
    c33.3-36.4,40.3-79.6,40.3-129.2c0-91.4,0-167.9,0-254.1c0-23.8-6.2-35-30.8-41.4c-86.6-22.2-161.2-24.6-260.8,9.5
    c0,19.2,0,36.9,0,54.7c0,133,0.2,266,0.2,399c0,133-0.1,266-0.2,399c0,17.8,0,35.5,0,54.7c99.6,34.1,174.2,31.7,260.8,9.5
    c24.6-6.4,31.2-17.6,30.8-41.4c-1.4-84.7,0-169.4,0-254.1c0-50.4-7-92.8-40.3-129.2C589.9,528.6,585.1,516.7,586,504.5z M449.1,207
    v-45.7c0-22.1,17.9-40,40-40c4.7,0,9.5,0,14.3,0c22.2,0,40.1,18,40,40.2c-0.4,81.1-1.8,154.6-1.8,232.4c-1,19.5-22.6,44.5-41.4,55.2
    c-31,17.7-51.2,1.1-51.2-35.3C448.9,344.9,449.1,275.9,449.1,207z M489,885.2c-22.1,0-40-17.9-40-40v-45.7
    c0-68.9-0.2-137.9-0.1-206.8c0-36.4,20.2-53,51.2-35.3c18.8,10.7,40.4,35.7,41.4,55.2c0,77.8,1.4,151.3,1.8,232.4
    c0.1,22.2-17.8,40.2-40,40.2C498.5,885.2,493.7,885.2,489,885.2z"/>
</svg>
```

I've tried changing the 1000 in the **viewBox** and **enable-background** attributes but neither had an effect when imported to the canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the viewBox to `350.7 23.6 291.7 959.3`, which is the boundary of the shape (I used the `getBBox()` method to find it).

Alternatively you could try this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 291.7 960">
<path d="M236 481.5h0.2c-0.1 -0.4 -0.1 -0.8 -0.1 -1.2c0 -0.4 0.1 -0.8 0.1 -1.2H236c-0.8 -12.2 3.9 -24.2 16 -37.3c33.3 -36.4 40.3 -79.6 40.3 -129.2c0 -91.4 0 -167.9 0 -254.1c0 -23.8 -6.2 -35 -30.8 -41.4c-86.6 -22.2 -161.2 -24.6 -260.8 9.5c0 19.2 0 36.9 0 54.7c0 133 0.2 266 0.2 399c0 133 -0.1 266 -0.2 399c0 17.8 0 35.5 0 54.7c99.6 34.1 174.2 31.7 260.8 9.5c24.6 -6.4 31.2 -17.6 30.8 -41.4c-1.4 -84.7 0 -169.4 0 -254.1c0 -50.4 -7 -92.8 -40.3 -129.2C240 505.6 235.1 493.7 236 481.5zM99.1 184v-45.7c0 -22.1 17.9 -40 40 -40c4.7 0 9.5 0 14.3 0c22.2 0 40.1 18 40 40.2c-0.4 81.1 -1.8 154.6 -1.8 232.4c-1 19.5 -22.6 44.5 -41.4 55.2c-31 17.7 -51.2 1.1 -51.2 -35.3C98.9 321.9 99.1 252.9 99.1 184zM139 862.2c-22.1 0 -40 -17.9 -40 -40v-45.7c0 -68.9 -0.2 -137.9 -0.1 -206.8c0 -36.4 20.2 -53 51.2 -35.3c18.8 10.7 40.4 35.7 41.4 55.2c0 77.8 1.4 151.3 1.8 232.4c0.1 22.2 -17.8 40.2 -40 40.2C148.5 862.2 143.7 862.2 139 862.2z"/>
```

I've translated the shape by (-350, -23) using [this](http://www.petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-transforms) so it should start at (0, 0).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how did you use the getBBox() method? I may be able to use that instead of editing all 78 of the svg files i'm having this issue with :p

Comment: Add an id to the path, then use `document.getElementById(id).getBBox()`. That will return an object with `x`, `y`, `width` and `height` properties.

Comment: Those properties can be directly used for the four viewBox values.